# encog java exporting network weights

Tags: java, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, neural-network, encog

I am using encog to do some of my university assignments and I would like to export a list of all the connections in the networks and their associated weights.

I saw the `dumpWeights()` function that is part of the `BasicMLNetwork` class (im using Java), but this only provides me with the weights with no information about the connections.

Does anyone know of a good way to achieve this?

Thanks In Advance
Bidski

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, use the BasicNetwork.getWeight.  You can loop over all of your layers and neurons.  Just specify the two neurons that you want the weight between.  Here is how it is called:

```
/**
     * Get the weight between the two layers.
     * @param fromLayer The from layer.
     * @param fromNeuron The from neuron.
     * @param toNeuron The to neuron.
     * @return The weight value.
     */
    public double getWeight(final int fromLayer, 
            final int fromNeuron,
            final int toNeuron) {
```

I just added the following function to Encog's BasicNetwork class to dump the weights and structure.  It will be in the next Encog release (3.4), its already on [GitHub](https://github.com/encog/encog-java-core/commit/85d40167899573c48847ab05b8a3bfc3a3630103).  For now, here is the code, it is a decent tutorial on how to extract the weights from Encog:

```
    public String dumpWeightsVerbose() {
    final StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    for (int layer = 0; layer < this.getLayerCount() - 1; layer++) {
        int bias = 0;
        if (this.isLayerBiased(layer)) {
            bias = 1;
        }

        for (int fromIdx = 0; fromIdx < this.getLayerNeuronCount(layer)
                + bias; fromIdx++) {
            for (int toIdx = 0; toIdx < this.getLayerNeuronCount(layer + 1); toIdx++) {
                String type1 = "", type2 = "";

                if (layer == 0) {
                    type1 = "I";
                    type2 = "H" + (layer) + ",";
                } else {
                    type1 = "H" + (layer - 1) + ",";
                    if (layer == (this.getLayerCount() - 2)) {
                        type2 = "O";
                    } else {
                        type2 = "H" + (layer) + ",";
                    }
                }

                if( bias ==1 && (fromIdx ==  this.getLayerNeuronCount(layer))) {
                    type1 = "bias";
                } else {
                    type1 = type1 + fromIdx;
                }

                result.append(type1 + "-->" + type2 + toIdx
                        + " : " + this.getWeight(layer, fromIdx, toIdx)
                        + "\n");
            }
        }
    }

    return result.toString();
}
```

Comment: If I am iterating over the neurons in a layer using getLayerNeuronCount() does that include the bias as well or would I need to consider that separately?

Comment: Yes, the bias weight is the last weight on each layer.

Comment: Using getWeight(). The toNeuron parameter, is that implicitly assumed to be a neuron in the next layer? And are layer and neuron numbers in the range of 0 to layerCount() - 1 (or layerNeuronCount() - 1)?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  I added some example code, see edit above.